# Problems with UV wrapping not baking

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking, error

[image]I’m following this YouTube tutorial https://youtu.be/sPKWR7Lcs3w and from about the 46th mark forward I can seem to get mine to work. I create the “displace” image and do everything exactly as shown but once I go to bake it like at the 47th mark, his will succeed while mine still results in an error. 
If you could help me with this that would be EXTREMELY helpful!
Thanks!
- Colby

Comment: IMO an answer would need a way to confirm _"everything exactly as shown"_

Comment: I've added an image to show you what I mean. Do you notice any points where I've gone wrong to cause this error now? batFINGER?

Comment: Some things to check: 1) if you check the box "selected to active" it expects to concern more than one object, so make sure that you have all relevant objects selected, and the one you want to bake to selected last so that it is the active object. 2) it might be that the difference between the two meshes is so little that it registers as near-black unless the bake is normalized (check that box and see)

Comment: In the outliner all of your meshes are disabled in render (the camera icons).

Comment: Thank you so much @Denis ! that did solve all of my problems. You are a life saver!

Answer (score -1):

Denis was correct! Thank you so much!
The camera icons are turned off as default and simply switching those on allowed the bake to process and solve all my problems!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/61629)

Comment: what do you mean @Sazerac ? I followed the steps Denis provided me with and that in turn solved all of my problems. I don't understand how you're saying that does not answer the question. I asked the question - and now I know how to do it properly. question answered